# IKVM jar to dll issues

Tags: java, c#, maven, dll, ikvm

I'm having hard times trying to convert my *.jar* library in *.dll* and make it working by IKVM framework.
I wrote a Java library that works fine since it has been tested succesfully in several java projects, but I strongly need the .dll for .NET.

When I launch the command:

```
ikvm -jar mylib.jar
```

everything is ok (I also tried with a Main file to be sure: it works).

But, when I type:

```
ikvmc -target:library mylib.jar
```

I got a lot of warnings but still it creates the .dll file. It is important to say that ALL the warnings are related to libraries that I DO NOT use in my project, but I am pretty sure are in the packages I imported in Maven that are essential to me.
I don't know if the true problem is in this step since I read online to ignore those warnings, but to be sure I post a little bit of the output:

```
warning IKVMC0100: Class "junit.framework.TestCase" not found
warning IKVMC0100: Class "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" not found
warning IKVMC0100: Class "javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream" not found
warning IKVMC0100: Class "org.junit.Assert" not found
warning IKVMC0100: Class "junit.framework.TestSuite" not found
warning IKVMC0100: Class "org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MatchingTask" not   found
```

Let us suppose this step is ok, now I have to import the IKVM libraries and the mylib.dll file in the *References* of my C# app. I did and the outcome is pretty strange: the autocomplete environment suggest me to use only 4 Java classes, ignoring the 99% of the others. I suppose that something went wrong, but it's pretty hard to me understand where and how to fix it.

Just more helpful info: I'm using Maven, Java8 (sdk 1.8) and IKVM 8.
I also tried the same with IKVM 7 and still got the same errors.
In the end, this is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.fra.mylibrary</groupId>
<artifactId>MyLibrary</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>MYLIBRARY</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.owlapi/owlapi-distribution -->
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.owlapi/owlapi-distribution -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.owlapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>owlapi-distribution</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.antlr/antlr4-runtime -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr4-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.owlapi/jfact -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.owlapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jfact</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.4</version>
    </dependency>



</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- ANTLR4 -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr4-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>antlr4</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Maven Assembly Plugin to create Jar -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Maven Compiler Plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove all code related to latest version of method and classes , and change it to lower version of library of java , may it work , because I have same error like this